# Oracle CTE Merge

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, ora-00928

I am trying a simple merge statement using a CTE(Common table expression) . But it gives an error

```
MERGE INTO  emp targ USING (
*
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
```

Is the CTE not allowed in a merge statement?  My Sql is below:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT empno, ename 
    FROM EMP)
MERGE INTO emp targ USING (SELECT * 
                             FROM cte) src
  ON (targ.empno = src.empno)
WHEN MATCHED THEN update 
   SET targ.ename = src.ename
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN insert
    (empno,ename)
  VALUES
    (src.empno,src.ename)
/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The WITH clause is for use with a SELECT statement.

[From the documents:](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2077142)
"You can specify this clause in any top-level **SELECT** statement and in most types of subqueries." (emphasis mine).

[Here is a possible workaround](http://www.orafaq.com/node/1879#comment-4712) if you really need to do this, from ORAFAQ. [The main blog writeup is here.](http://www.orafaq.com/node/1879)