# Identify missing numbers in an Oracle Table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a number sequence field in a table that has some gaps/skipped numbers in it. I need to identify the skipped numbers. The only solution I can think of is to use iterative/cursor based loops and I suspect that will be fairly slow. Is there a faster method?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968493/how-to-check-any-missing-number-from-a-series-of-numbers) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364247/sql-find-missing-int-values-in-mostly-ordered-sequential-series)

Comment: Thanks user75ponic!